# Loop returns the current page's permalink and guid instead of the post in the loop

Tags: plugins, wp-query, loop, shortcode

[image: Visual Debugging]

Here is my code:

```
global $post;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$array = get_object_vars($the_query); //convert the object into an array (manual workaround)
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $count = 0; //start an iteration count
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
       <? $the_query->the_post(); ?>
       <?php $postarray = get_object_vars($array['posts'][$count]); 
    //convert the post object into an array
  ?> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <h4><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <?php the_permalink() ?>
                <!-- the guid is now accessable -->
                    <a href="<?php echo $postarray['guid']; ?>">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?  endwhile;
else :
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;
```

I have referenced other questions about this, however my `global $post;` IS outside the loop (as referenced from [Post Loop not Returning Permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240856/post-loop-not-returning-permalink/240870)) and I have also already tried using the range of functions for grabbing/showing the permalink and guid value (as referenced from [`get_the_permalink()` Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/)

also its worth noting that `get_the_ID()` returned the currently viewed page id NOT the iterated post id

also this is all contained within a shortcode function.

any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: So, do you mean that the loop is returning the correct title, but wrong permalink? Also as a side note, never use short php tags `<?`, always use  the full `<?php` form.

Comment: Can you remove the short tag and verify 100% it has nothing to do with this issue? It's a massive red herring. Can you also verify that nothing is hooked into the permalink filters?

Comment: I found A solution ill amend my answer to demonstrate my solution.. 

yes the title is correct but the ID permalink and guid were all returning the currently viewed page values

Comment: I amended my question to show my (non ideal) solution. If anyone has a better solution feel free

Comment: In addition to what @TomJNowell Said, I would also remove the global post and see if it has anything to do with that.

Comment: noted: when i removed the global $post declaration, it had no noticable effect on the script

Comment: Then I doubt there is a problem with your code. Something might be hooking into your permalink filter, try disabling all the plugins and switching to default theme.

Comment: One thing to note- while the GUID *looks like* the permalink, it's not the permalink and can't be relied upon to always be correct. Always use the API to get post data, don't get it directly from the object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually surprised that your code is working. There are several typos in it that should be throwing fatal errors.

```
global $post;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
       <?php $the_query->the_post(); 
       $id = get_the_ID(); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <h4><?php echo get_the_title( $id ); ?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt( $id ); ?></p>
                    <?php echo get_the_permalink( $id ); ?>

                    <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink( $id ); ?>">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php  endwhile;
else :
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;
```

You mentioned that `get_the_ID();` function works fine. So, what you can do is to manually feed the permalink function with the ID, something that I've done in my answer.

Also, you have a couple of missing semicolons, which I've corrected in the answer.

As a side note, ever use short PHP tags `<?`. They are deprecated, and on my system they even throw a fatal error. Always use full `<?php` tags.

Comment: if you read my post again, you will notice that i wrote get_the_ID() is NOT working.. in caps

Comment: i noticed the typo, was a result of playing with different variables. still does not answer why the permalink and the id and the guid will not return in the loop